# Render output of a php file inside a div as a sublayout in a component view as virtuemart sublayout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.5.1, and i have a component and a system plugin,
In one of my view in the component i m checking if the plugin is installed then i am creating a div, In this div i want to render a php file as a sub layout, the file i want to render will be part of the plugin installed.

How to use the file as a sub layout, please provide some ideas i tried using `JLayoutHelper` but i couldn't accomplish it.I tried searching but got no successful results.
In view:

```
$plu=JPluginHelper::getPlugin("system", "myplugin");
 <?php if(count($plu)!=0){ ?>
    <div class="panel-body contentbar">
    <?php   $layout = new JLayoutFile(JPATH_SITE."/plugins/system/myplugin");
    $layout->render("mycus.php");
    ?></div><?php } ?>
```

What am I suppose to do to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving the correct syntax for JLayout

Instead of this

```
   $layout = new JLayoutFile(JPATH_SITE."/plugins/system/myplugin");
   $layout->render("mycus.php");
```

Try this code

```
 $layout = new JLayoutFile('mycus', $basePath = JPATH_ROOT .'/plugins/system/myplugin');

 $layout->render($params);
```

will load and render the `'mycus.php'` layout file found in `JPATH_ROOT .'/plugins/system/myplugin'` directory. $params are the parameters to be passed to that file.

Check this page https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Sharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout

Comment: thanx for help but this doesn't help i want to render the output of php file inside the div